# Gradle: create a task passing parameters as command line

Tags: android, gradle, sonarqube

I manually run the following tasks:

```
./gradlew clean jacocoTestReportFree sonarqube -Pflavor=free
./gradlew clean jacocoTestReportPaid sonarqube -Pflavor=paid
```

Now I will like to create a new task to launch both of them. This is the code.

```
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
//SonarQube configuration.
sonarqube {
    def flavorName = ''
    if (project.hasProperty('flavor')) {
        //read the flavor from properties.
        flavorName = flavor
        androidVariant flavorName + "Debug"
    } else {
        androidVariant 'debug'
    }
    properties {
        property 'sonar.host.url', 'http://localhost:9000'
        property "sonar.projectName", "Java Example " + flavorName
        property "sonar.projectKey", "jonceski.kliment.jacococoverageexample." + flavorName
        property 'sonar.java.source', '8'
        property 'sonar.sourceEncoding', 'UTF-8'
        property "sonar.language", "java"
        property "sonar.login", "admin"
        property "sonar.password", "admin"

        property 'sonar.java.binaries', 'build/intermediates/classes/' + flavorName + "/debug"
        property 'sonar.java.test.binaries', 'build/intermediates/classes/' + flavorName + "/debug"
        property 'sonar.junit.reportsPath', 'build/test-results/test' + flavorName.capitalize() +'DebugUnitTest'
        property 'sonar.jacoco.reportPath', fileTree(dir: project.projectDir, includes: ['**/*.exec'])
        property 'sonar.jacoco.itReportPath', fileTree(dir: project.projectDir, includes: ['**/*.ec'])
        property 'sonar.java.coveragePlugin', 'jacoco'
        property 'sonar.exclusions', '**/*.js,**/*.css,**/*.html'
    }
}
```

This is what i've try without success.

```
task coverageFlavorFree {
    doFirst {
        clean
    }
    doLast {
        jacocoTestReportFree
        sonarqube(flavor="free")
    }
}
```

Comment: i do think you do a lot of additional configuration. Sonarqube plugin will set the sources etc based on your source sets, so maybe you want to investigate into gradle configurations, where you can define multiple configurations with different outputs. this might be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In gradle you shouldn't just call other tasks. The correct way of doing these things is by creating tasks for every flavor and declaring their dependencies.

Here is a full working example:

```
plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.7"
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    flavorDimensions 'version'

    productFlavors {
        professional {
            dimension 'version'
        }
        free {
            dimension 'version'
        }
    }
}

sonarqube {
}

task SonarQubeAll(group: 'SonarQube') {

}

android.applicationVariants.all { flavor ->
    task("${flavor.name}SonarQube", group: 'SonarQube') {
        description = 'Sets the sonarqube configuration'
        finalizedBy 'sonarqube'
        SonarQubeAll.dependsOn("${flavor.name}SonarQube")

        doLast {
            println("Setting flavor to ${flavor.name} for ${project.sonarqube.androidVariant}")
            project.sonarqube.androidVariant = flavor.name
            //TODO: Set other flavor dependent sonarqube properties here
            // using project.sonarqube.properties...
        }
    }
}
```

This will genereate a task for each flavor called `{flavor}SonarQube` as well as a root task called `SonarQubeAll`. Each flavor task will be finalized by the actual sonarqube task. The root task will have all the other tasks as dependency, causing them all to be executed.

Here is the dependency graph:

```
:myapplication:SonarQubeAll
+--- :myapplication:freeDebugSonarQube
+--- :myapplication:freeReleaseSonarQube
+--- :myapplication:professionalDebugSonarQube
\--- :myapplication:professionalReleaseSonarQube
```

Comment: Yes it does. Dynamically creating tasks is supported by gradle and not considered a hack.

Comment: I mostly meant using `finalizedBy` with a project wide configuration of `sonarqube` just before. How does this behave with parallel executions? Is it guaranteed that `androidVariant` isn't reset before `sonarqube` executes?

Comment: The `sonarqube` settings are always project wide since that's how the plugin works. So there is no way of running it in parallel anyways without getting race conditions. Multiple tasks in `finalizedBy`are not executed in parallel.

Comment: @davidgiga1993 amazing answer. I didn't know about finalyzeBy.